# Why doesn't marker.dragging.disable() work?

Tags: leaflet

The following code receives an error on the lines for enabling and disabling the marker dragging ("Unable to get property 'disable' of undefined or null reference").  The markers show up on the map just fine and are draggable as the creation line indicates.  Placing an alert in place of the enable line produces a proper object so I believe the marker is defined.  Is there something I need to do to enable the IHandler interface?  Or am I missing something else?

```
var marker = L.marker(L.latLng(lat,lon), {icon:myIcon, draggable:'true'})
    .bindLabel(name, {noHide: true,direction: 'right'});
marker._myId = name;
if (mode === 0) {
    marker.dragging.enable();
} else {
    marker.dragging.disable();
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I haven't found an answer but my workaround was this:

```
var temp;
if (mode === 0) {
    temp = true;
} else {
    temp = false;
}
var marker = L.marker(L.latLng(lat,lon), {icon:myIcon, draggable:temp})
    .bindLabel(name, {noHide: true,direction: 'right'});
marker._myId = name;
```

Fortunately I change my icon when it is draggable.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem today (perhaps the same one) it was due to a bug in leaflet (see [leaflet issue #2578](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/2578)) where changing the icon of a marker invalidates any drag handling set on that marker. This makes any calls to `marker.dragging.disable()` fail.

The [fix](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/2766) hasn't made it into leaflets master at time of writing. A workaround is to change the icon *after* updating the draggable status if possible.

```
marker.dragging.disable();
marker.setIcon(marker_icon);
```

Comment: Strange, I saw your answer, and it helped, but it was the other way round for me. From an initial state of draggable at creation of marker, I set disable(), then changed icon, and disabled() showed true after disable, but false again after the set icon. I simply set icon first, then disabled the drag, and it works now.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code to make an object draggable. Set `elementToDrag` to the object you wish to make draggable, which is in your case: "marker"

```
var draggable = new L.Draggable(elementToDrag);
draggable.enable();
```

To disable dragging, use the following code:

```
draggable.disable()
```

> A class for making DOM elements draggable (including touch support).
>   Used internally for map and marker dragging. Only works for elements
>   that were positioned with DomUtil#setPosition

[leaflet: Draggable](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#draggable)

If you wish to only disable the drag option of a marker, then you can use the following code (where "marker" is the name of your marker object):

```
marker.dragging.disable(); 
marker.dragging.enable();
```